# how to modify table values in database

Tags: android

hi i am new to andriod.I am creating a table and inserting the values into table by  using sql lite.Now i need to change vales based on the id.how can i done this pls post some code.Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you've tried [UPDATE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)?

Comment: i need it in android sql lite,not in sql

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SQLiteDatabase.update method. Method will return number of rows affected. In your case it should be a single row.

```
public int update(int id, ContentValues values, SQLiteDatabase db){
 String selection = ID_COLUMN_NAME + "=" + Integer.toString(id); 
 count = db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, selection, null);
 return count;
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[]

p.s. sorry, StackOverflow corrupts the url